# Understanding return value of a function

Tags: javascript, function

So I'm doing some challenges on freecodecamp, I got stuck on one that says: 
"Make a function that looks through an array of objects (first argument) and returns an array of all objects that have matching property and value pairs (second argument)." So I looked the for the answer and came accross the next code:

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  var arr = [];
  var keys = Object.keys(source);
  // Filter array and remove the ones that do not have the keys from source.
  arr = collection.filter(function(obj) {
    return keys.every(function(key) {
      return obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === source[key];
    });
  });

  return arr;
}
```

I understand what it does what I cant seem to get is the returns inside the collection.filter why do we need these two:

```
    return keys.every(function(key) {
      return obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === source[key];
```

Why the code doesn't work with only the second one.

Can someone explain this to me please.

Comment: It could work without `hasOwnProperty`, but if an ancestor of the object has properties, these would be considered for the child too.

Comment: Because you need to use `return` to return a value from a function. The first return is returning from the function passed to `every`. The second return is returning from `whatIsInAName`.

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty for more details on the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code:

```
arr = collection.filter(function(obj) {
    return keys.every(function(key) {
      return obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === source[key];
    });
```

First, (this is the main script to check wheter Collection's element match or not with the source)

```
keys.every(function(key) {
          return obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === source[key];
```

It will just return either **true/false** based on `obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === source[key];` condition. it checks every keys from `source`. If it finds just `one key` un-matched with the condition it will break the loop and return `false` otherwise (passed all the test [all keys and values from **source** the same with collection's element]) return true.

then

`arr = collection.filter(function(obj) {
        return true // false`

if it return `true`, the element obj from collection will be passed to `arr` otherwise `filtered / skipped`

Answer (score 0):

`collection.filter` is calling [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). It is used for removing elements from an array that don't meet certain criteria. The function passed as a parameter is used to determine whether an element meets that criteria. A return value of `false` means that the element should be removed from the array, while `true` means that the element should stay in the array.

If you don't give the function a `return` statement, it will return `undefined` for all of the elements of the array, which is a falsy value.

In ES6, you can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which don't require you to write `return`:

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  var keys = Object.keys(source);
  return collection.filter(obj =>
    keys.every(key =>
      obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === source[key];
    )
  );
}
```